# Disable Windows battling over the cursor position

Tags: c++, mouse-position

I've created an input class from rawinput to able to manage all mouseinputs as I please. However, as I'm going to set the sensitivity the cursor teleports for a microsecond to another location. I can only assume it is due to my cursor sensitivity differs from the windows own sensitivity. Update is like so;

```
void InputDevice::Update(LPARAM lParam)
    {
        memcpy(_last, _current, sizeof(bool) * KEY_CODE_CAP);
        _mouseCoord._deltaPos.x = 0;
        _mouseCoord._deltaPos.y = 0;
        HandleRawInput(lParam);

        _mouseCoord._pos.x += _mouseCoord._deltaPos.x * _sensitivity;
        _mouseCoord._pos.y += _mouseCoord._deltaPos.y * _sensitivity;
        SetCursorPos(_mouseCoord._pos.x, _mouseCoord._pos.y);
    }
```

How can I completely disable windows messing up my cursor in my own program?